# write an error file while load large dataset into postgresql

Tags: postgresql

While loading a large file, is it possible to redirect errors to an error file while rest of the data is loaded?

I'm loading about 4 gigs of data into postgresql using the copy command. The data is generated from several hundred files from various sources, which means the data can be very noisy. It takes about an hour to normalize data and every time there is an error, I have to wait fix the  error and wait an hour. This simply isn't working.

Is there a way to either load as much data as possible, and write error messages to a file or perhaps even run psql copy's validation logic through the whole file, even after errors have been detected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, PostgreSQL doesn't offer error handling during `COPY`. It's an oft-requested feature, but for internal design/architectural reasons not an easy one to implement, and performance of `COPY` would likely suffer quite badly. Future versions may offer `COPY` filters but probably not row-by-row error handling.

Instead, `COPY` the data to a `TEMPORARY` or `UNLOGGED` table, then use SQL to insert it into the real target table with appropriate filters to detect bad data, along the lines of:

```
INSERT INTO real_table(col1, col2, col3)
SELECT 
   col1,
   col2,
   col3
FROM temp_table
WHERE ... validation clauses ...
```

This only helps if the file to be `COPY`'d is well-formed in its entirety, though, as errors in the `COPY` its self - structurally, or in the representation of the data types - will still cause the load to fail. It's also only useful if you can usefully predict which data will cause an error. If you can't predict failures you can use a PL/PgSQL function with a `BEGIN ... EXCEPTION` clause to transfer the data from the temp table, but this imposes a big performance hit because of the looping and because it's setting up a subtransaction for each row.

If you have malformed types (i.e. dates that `datein` will reject) you can `COPY` the whole data stream into a table that has `text` columns for suspect inputs. Then validate afterwards. This won't help if your input is structurally malformed though - bad quoting/escaping, too many columns on some lines, etc.

If your data's really difficult I strongly recommend looking at a proper ETL tool like Pentaho Kettle or Talend Studio. They take some more learning, but they're much better at ingesting bad data. There's also `pg_bulkload` to consider as an option, though I don't know how maintained it is.

Comment: Thanks @Craig, I'll check out the ETL tools. So far I was combining all data files into a single large file, cleaning it up and copying it. I think I'll operate one data source file at a time and figure out a strategy to deal with failed files.